# Upper-half space of a manifold with boundary

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology

Suppose that $X$ is a manifold with boundary and suppose that $x$ is a boundary point. Define the *upper half space* $H_x(X)$ in $T_x(X)$ to be the image of $\mathbb{H^k}$ under $d \phi_0:\mathbb{R^k} \to T_x(X)$ where $\phi:U \to X$ is a local parametrization with $\phi(0)=x$. I need to prove that $H_x(X)$ does not depend on the choice of local parametization.

My Try :

Suppose $\psi:V \to X$ be another parametrization with $\psi(0)=x$ as well. Can I assume that by shrinking(?) $U$ and $V$ we'd have $\phi(U)=\psi(V)$ ? Why can I assume such a thing ?

Assuming that, I can say $h=\psi^{-1} \circ \phi : U \to V$ is a diffeomorphism and the result follows from differentiating $h$.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Try using $\phi(U)\cap \psi(V)$.

Comment: @Neal Thanks ! Got it

Comment: How did you solve it? Because you have to show that $dh(H_k)=H_k$, right?